# Which VNC client is the most convenient one?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

My every day workstation is an Ubuntu 22.04. Sometimes I work at the same time remotely on a Windows desktop via VNC. For the connection currently I am using RealVNC on both server and client sides.

On the client side I am mostly satisfied with RealVNC's VNC Viewer, even if it has some limitations (it is not free, and it is free of charge only for a maximum of 5 configured clients). But it also has an annoying bug: if I change the current window to work on the remote desktop, the Alt key is stuck (the shortcut for the change is Alt-Tab on KDE). I need to press the Alt key inside the remote window again to "unstick" the Alt key. This is very annoying and slows down work if I have to switch back and forth between the desktops.

The RealVNC developers seem to unable to identify and solve this issue, so I am hesitating to choose another VNC client (and eventually, another server, if required). Is there a better option than RealVNC?